# client server communication through JNLP

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start, jnlp

Is there a way for any java swing (GUI) application deployed via jnlp; to interact back with the server ?

Scenario: A simple exam application has to register the candidate for a specific client system and after the exam is done the marks have to be sent to the server.

In the above scenario, communication between client GUI (java swing application) and the server (java swing application) is required for exchange of information like registration id and marks.

The JNLP API provides System.getProperty and System.setProperties methods in the resources Element but the usage of system properties are limited.

Is there any reference or resource that I can have please

Comment: Communication between the app. launched by JWS & the server it was launched from can be done exactly the same way as from a non JWS based Swing app. The only difference is that a JWS app. would need `all-permissions` to relay information back to another server, and that it is slightly easier to determine where to return the information if it is the 'home server', since the JNLP API can provide the URL to the server on which it is based.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this helps !